# Required String parameter is not present

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, okhttp

I want to send post request from my Android apps to Spring Boot. I use okhttp to send the HTTP post request in JSON. The code is like this:

Every time I send post request using the Android request I got 400 bad request parameter 'name' is not present","path":"/newcustomer". But when I use postman it works.

```
    Java
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Log.d("okhttphandleruserreg", "called");
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jsonObject.put("name", name);
        jsonObject.put("email", email);
        jsonObject.put("username", username);
        jsonObject.put("password", password);
        jsonObject.put("month", month);
        jsonObject.put("dayOfMonth", dayOfMonth);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());

    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
    builder.url(params[0]);
    builder.post(body);
    Request request = builder.build();

    Spring Boot
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newcustomer", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public Customer newCust(@RequestParam(value="name") String name,
                        @RequestParam(value="email") String email,
                        @RequestParam(value="username") String username,
                        @RequestParam(value="password") String password,
                        @RequestParam(value="month") int month,
                        @RequestParam(value="dayOfMonth") int dayOfMonth
)
```

Comment: In postman you might used these values as params instead of request Body

Comment: This is because your back-end is expecting the data as Request Query Params, But you are posting as Request Body. Either you post the data as request params OR better to improve the back-end. Accept the data as @RequestBody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have implemented your back-end */newcustomer* API suggests you are expecting the request payload to be raw request params within the request form data.

Assuming the server side API is your contract, thus should remain as is, your client code should be updated as follows:

```java
Log.d("okhttphandleruserreg", "called");

// here you create your request body as as a Form one
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
  .add("name", "test")
  .add("email", "test@domain.com")
  .add("username", "test")
  .add("username", "test")
  .add("month", "january")
  .add("dayOfMonth", "1")
  .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(params[0])
  .post(formBody)
  .build();

// call your request
```

Comment: instead of requestParam here, in this use case, better if we use RequestBody @tmarwen

Answer (score 1):

You are using Request Params in Spring Boot but whereas in Android code you sending that as Request Body.

Please change any one of the above. Better if you use RequestBody in both places.

```
class Customer
{
String name:
String email:
String username;
String password;
int month;
int dayofthemonth;

//getter and setters
}

public Customer newCust(@RequestBody Customer newcustomer)
{
}
```